# List of English word subjunctives

Tags: tenses, dictionaries, inflections, inflectional-morphology

I'm working on a word cloud application and thought it would be useful to group different forms of the same word together.  For example, "rides", "ride", "riding", and "rode" would all be grouped as "ride".

<strike>I'm pretty certain "ride" is the subjunctive form of these words, but please forgive me if I'm mistaken.</strike>

Is there a list of all English words and what their subjunctive form would be?

**EDIT:**

Thank you to all for clarifying my misuse of "subjunctive". As Brian described below, I am interested in a list of "base forms" or "dictionary forms" and all their inflected forms. Does anyone know of a list of this information that would be in a usable format?

By usable, I mean in a flat file, a database, an API, etc.

Comment: The verb in a subjunctive clause is in the 'plain' (infinitive) form. All verbs of course have a plain form, so potentially all verbs can be used in subjunctive clauses: _I insist that I **be** kept informed_  ; _They demanded that I **attend** the meeting_, and so on.

Comment: As essentially every word can be verbed in English, your list would be potentially infinite in length.

Answer (score 2):

Historically, there were two subjunctives in English, the present and the past.

The present subjunctive is *in every case* identical to the infinitive. It is today used only (by some people) after verbs like "mandate" and "require", and in a few set phrases like "Long live ... "! (In my view, mention of it should be eliminated in discussing the grammar of modern English, and verbs like "mandate" should be stated to take the infinitive without 'to').

The past subjunctive is *in every case but one* identical to the simple past - the one exception being *were* in place of *was*. It is used by many people, but not all, for *irrealis* (or *counter-factual*) conditionals: *If I were rich, ...*.

Comment: I have to wonder if OP is really concerned about the subjunctive at all; I suspect he may simply be looking for the term *base form* or *dictionary form,* with which to label the headword of a collection that also includes inflected forms..

Comment: @BrianDonovan, yes, you are correct. I do not deny my ignorance to the definition and usage of "subjunctive", but am truly interested in the "base form" as you describe.